# How To Implement iCloud Backup

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I've watched a couple of talks on iCloud and most focus on its three core services (key-value storage, document storage, and CloudKit) yet all I want to know is how to turn on backups so if my user's phone is stolen or smashed:

1. My app will have already created a recent backup on the cloud
2. My app will restore that backup when the user gets their new phone

A few notes:

1. My app uses CoreData
2. I'm not looking for a solution for syncing devices, just backup/restore
3. I also intend to continue relying on local storage as the primary data sources, so the app works even when the phone has no internet connection

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886331/full-coredata-uploading-backup-to-icloud-drive-and-restore-if-need) but the answer is a link and the link is dead.  I can't find anything explaining how to do this, please help!

Comment: iCloud backup is something that the user turns on in settings for their entire device.  If you want your app to store its data in iCloud then you need to use one of the three services you mentioned.  You could backup your Core Data sqlite database using document storage or you could use a CloudKit persistent store for Core Data such as https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3

Comment: @Paulw11 So are you saying that if they turn on iCloud backup, I need to do absolutely nothing? And that I only need to use the services I mentioned if I want to forego local storage in favor of iCloud storage?

Comment: If they turn on iCloud backup then their device, including any data saved by apps that isn't flagged *do not back up* (By default an app's document directory will be backed up) is periodically backed up to the cloud.  If you use something like CloudKit then you can push data to the cloud immediately and synchronise it across multiple devices.  iCloud backup will lose data between the last backup and when the device is lost.  CloudKit will be real-time as long as there is network connectivity.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the clarification. Any idea why my #1 complaint (in reviews) is that "there is no backup" and "would be 5 stars if it had backup option"? You said that it happens automatically unless I tell it not to but my users don't seem believe its backing up. Do I need to turn on iCloud for it to work?

Comment: Users need to enable the iCloud backup, and they can only use it by restoring their entire phone. Perhaps users don't know that your apps data is backed up along with their phone backup, perhaps there is some other scenario in which they want to restore their data